# PKCS7_sign returns null

Tags: c++, ios, openssl, pkcs#7, pkcs#12

I've been trying to get a pkcs#7 signature to happen in c++, and I've only succeeded in growing more gray hairs.

I get a *.cer file from Apple, and build a *.p12 file using [Keychain Access](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1X10zCzhukI).  Once I have that, I fire up Eclipse, and slurp in the p12 file that I generated.  The rest can be found below:

```
BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
FILE *fp = fopen((char *)"/path/to/cert.p12", "rb");
EVP_PKEY *pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
X509 *cert = X509_new();
STACK_OF(X509) *ca = sk_X509_new_null();
PKCS12 *p12 = NULL;
PKCS7 *p7 = NULL;

BIO_read_filename(bio, '/path/to/data.txt');

if (!fp) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error opening cert.p12\n");
  exit(1);
}

d2i_PKCS12_fp(fp, &p12);

if (!p12) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error reading PKCS#12 file\n");
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  exit (1);
}

// That's amazing.  I have the same combination on my luggage!
if (!PKCS12_parse(p12, (char *)"12345", &pkey, &cert, &ca)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing PKCS#12 file\n");
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  exit (1);
}

p7 = PKCS7_sign(cert, pkey, ca, bio, PKCS7_TEXT);
```

I tried dumping out the cert, pkey and chain to a file.  It all worked as expected (the chain was empty, but I wasn't expecting anything).  It looks like p7 is still null after the signature.  I tried to use the p7 object, and I get a segmentation fault.

Anyone ever come across anything like this?

Comment: @noloader, one thing that I noticed, is that `PKCS12_parse(p12, (char *)"12345", &pkey, &cert, &ca)` makes a pkcs8 private key, and a x.509 cert.  I know that x.509 is what it's supposed to be, but I'm not sure about the pkcs8.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone ever come across anything like this?

Do you mean hard to use and documentation with an opportunity for improvement? Yes.

Here's the official OpenSSL docs: [PKCS7_sign(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_sign.html).

---

```
$ cd openssl-1.0.1f/apps
$ grep -R PKCS7_sign *
smime.c: p7 = PKCS7_sign(NULL, NULL, other, in, flags);
```

Here's the sample code from `smime.c`:

```
PKCS7 *p7 = NULL;
BIO *in = NULL, *out = NULL;
STACK_OF(X509) *other = NULL;
const EVP_MD *sign_md  
int flags = 0;

other = load_certs(bio_err,certfile,FORMAT_PEM, NULL, e, "certificate file");

sign_md = EVP_get_digestbyname("sha256");

flags |= PKCS7_STREAM;
flags |= PKCS7_PARTIAL;
p7 = PKCS7_sign(NULL, NULL, other, in, flags);

for (i = 0; i < sk_OPENSSL_STRING_num(sksigners); i++) {
    ...
    signer = load_cert(bio_err, signerfile,FORMAT_PEM, NULL, e, "signer certificate");
    PKCS7_sign_add_signer(p7, signer, key, sign_md, flags))
}

PKCS7_final(p7, in, flags);
...

PEM_write_bio_PKCS7(out, p7);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I found the demos for openssl, and I'm going to try to see if there's anything that can help me.  Specifically, it looks like there's a few functions (load_certs(), specifically) that I need to understand before getting your code snippet working.  I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Sorry I could not offer something better. The [OpenSSL wiki](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php) does not have a PKCS7 example. I often work with OpenSSL, and grepping the sources is the best way I've found to see how to do things :(